# How to change immutable objects from an imported module in python?

Tags: python-3.x, immutability, python-module, mutable

I found myself struggling with this situation: if I have foo.py

```
# foo.py
test = 0
def changeTest(new):
    test = new
    print(f'New test value: {test}')
```

And I run this code:

```
import foo
print(foo.test)
foo.changeTest(5)
print(foo.test)
```

Outputs:

```
0
New test value: 5
0
```

I cannot get foo.test updated in my main.py. Whereas if I use an mutable object, say test = [0], I can access its new value.

```
# foo.py
test = [0]
def changeTest(new):
    test = [new]

# main.py
import foo.py
print(foo.test)
foo.changeTest(5)
print(foo.test)
## output
[0]
[5]
```

If I want a module where I keep some environment variables and some functions I want to be accessible from others, What is the best practice to access the module data? Was thinking in putting everything inside a class (so its mutable), but I really only need an instance.

Answer (score 0):

The function `changeTest()` treats `test` as a local variable, the `test` in the function is different from the global `test` in the module, you could try to declare test as a global variable.

This should work:

```
def change_test(new_value):
    global test
    test = new_value
```

Comment: So then, why I get the updated value in the case foo.test is a list, for instance. Is it then treated as global because is mutable?